# Exclude partners, contractors from sharepoint site

Tags: 2010, permissions, authentication, groups

I am creating a sharepoint site and struggling with the permissions.
My client provides IDs to the its partners and contractors the same way it provides to its employees.

I have to configure the sharepoint site permissions in such a way that all employees should have access to the site but contractors and partners should not.

One thing that comes to my mind is to get a secure AD group created which could hold only employees. I am not sure if this will work or not as i don't know much about AD and it is handled by a different vendor. In GAL i don't see any difference between contractors profile and employees profile.

Please suggest what options i have here.

Answer (score 1):

You should Create Different AD Account for your Contractors and Partners Different From all your FTE(Full Time Employees) lets call it All_Employees. Add All_Employees into your SharePoint Site which will give your FTE's Access to your site, but not Contractors . You should Contact your AD Vendor and Request this information from their's end to apply these.  Please Dont add All_Authenticated group, this will give out access to your sharepoint site to all users in your trsuted AD account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to create a AD Group with AllEmployees and ADD that Group into Sharepoint